# Java hashing (simple)

Tags: java, hash

I need a short way to turn **strings** into **ints** and back. I'm talking about  a way to turn `A into 1, B into 2, C into 3, D into 4...`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply convert them like this

```
int n = ch - 'A' + 1;
```

`ch` will be containing the characters and `n` will give you the integer respectively.

You can convert them back to `char` like this.

```
char ch = (char) ('A'+n-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using `char` instead of `String` if you're only mapping a letter to a number.

```
int alphabetSize = 26;
char start = 'A';
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < alphabetSize; i++) {
    map.put(String.valueOf((char)(start + i)), i + 1);
}
```